# Xamarin forms Label height issue

Tags: ios, layout, label, xamarin.forms

I have a xaml page with Relative Layout > Grid(1row, 1col) + ActivityIndicator(1row, 1col)
Grid has a scrollview which has a stacklayout and a button. 
Stacklayout has a label with blank text and verticaloption set to FillAndExpand.

On Page Appearing i am getting a value from a service and changing the label value.

**Issue:** As it is the label is rendering with height as 0, If i set label's default value as "something", Height of label is = 1 line and only 1 line of text is visible. If i set it to something like "\n\n\n\n\n multiple times" i am getting a scrollbar in page as expected, but the height of label is equal to \n\n\n count and not equal to the content that comes on appearing.

What i can change so as to fix this problem? If code is required i can put it in here.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Grid Padding="0" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollView x:Name="Scroller1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
            <StackLayout x:Name="Stack1" Padding="20,20,20,0" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia">
                <Label x:Name="Label1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Lime" Text="{Binding DisclaimerText}"  />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Button Command="{Binding AgreeBtnTapCommand}" HeightRequest="50" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderRadius="0" Text="Agree" TextColor="White" >
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <controls:PageActivityIndicator RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes please put the code in

Comment: maybe if you add a FillAndExpand to the scrollview?

Comment: @Slepz no change. Issue is the height of label is based on its first value assigned and its not updating later on when its value is changing.

Comment: when all else fails, you can always use the "Label1.ForceLayout()" method. It's expensive, but so is spending hours trying to set a label height.